# How can I change color of UITabBarItem's title when it's selecetd

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

My env,

```
iOS6
Xcode 4.5.1
```

I want to change a color of UITabBarItem's title when it's selected.

I use CustomUITabBarItem for UITabBarItem.
- customUITabBarItem.m

```
@implementation customUITabBarItem

@synthesize customHighlightedImage;

-(UIImage *) selectedImage
{
    return self.customHighlightedImage;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [customHighlightedImage release];
    customHighlightedImage=nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "customUITabBarItem.h"


@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CustomUITabBarItem *tabItem = [[customUITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"first" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] tag:0]; 
    tabItem.customHighlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first_selected.png"];
    self.tabBarItem = tabItem;
    [tabItem release];
    tabItem = nil;
}
```

How can I change the color?

Comment: you can see this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148787/ios-change-tabbar-item-color-is-safe

Comment: you can see this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148787/ios-change-tabbar-item-color-is-safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 [self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f], UITextAttributeFont,
                                            [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                            [UIColor grayColor],        
                                            nil]];
```

And please ensure that this only works for iOS 5.0 or later.

Comment: Thanx a lot! however I need to add "forState:UIControlStateSelected" in the end. Anyway I can done well.

Answer (score 0):

```
//it easy to change color
-(void)your_method
{
// your actions
[tabItem setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Comment: Thank for your comment, but there is a warning, "UITabView may not be respond to setBackgroundColor" and the commands doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define SYSTEM_OS [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue]
- (void) setTabBarColors {

    if (SYSTEM_OS >= 5) {

        self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = [UIColor magentaColor];

        __block NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12.0f], UITextAttributeFont,
                                       [UIColor lightGrayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                       nil];



        __block NSDictionary *dict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12.0f], UITextAttributeFont,
                                       [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                       nil];

        [self.tabBarController.viewControllers enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIViewController * obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

            [obj.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:dict1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [obj.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:dict2 forState:UIControlStateSelected];

        }];

    }

}
```