# iOS: Increasing contrast on Tab items

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, tabitem, contrast

It is difficult to see my tab item images and text with the dark blue background I am using as you can see in this image. Is there a way to make them more bright when not selected?

[image]

Comment: check this out ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939399/tabbar-item-image-and-selectedimage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're targeting iOS 5, meaning that you can take advantage of the `UIAppearance` API. In that case, you need to do more than just set the background image of the tab bar; you need to set selected and unselected "finished" images for each tab bar item. By "finished", we mean that the default "shine" effect won't be applied before displaying your images; they'll be shown exactly as they are.

[Here's a great tutorial](http://felipecypriano.com/2012/02/27/how-to-customize-uitabbar-on-ios-5/) showing all the customizations you can apply.